# What is the best way to convert an array of strings into an array of objects in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say I have an array as follows:

```
types = ['Old', 'New', 'Template'];
```

I need to convert it into an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Old'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'New'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Template'
    }
]
```

Comment: `['Old', 'New', 'Template'].map((x,i) =>({ id: i + 1, name: x}))`

Comment: How do I map it to a new array of objects?

Comment: @notyetdecided answering instead of yurzui... simply: `let newArr = ['Old', 'New', 'Template'].map((x,i) =>({ id: i + 1, name: x}))` :)

Comment: The same thing happens here too as in the answer below. The newly created array of objects contains another object in the name field and not just the string. Can anyone solve this?

Comment: @notyetdecided are you sure that the types array doesn't contain objects? try debugging and checking out the actual values.

Comment: Yes is it just an array of srting values.

Comment: Works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/zALShswOwChBjoby56Lz?p=preview

Comment: You're right. I was actually experimenting with the wrong array. This works, no issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **map** to iterate over the original array and create new objects.

```js
let types = ['Old', 'New', 'Template'];

let objects = types.map((value, index) => {
  return {
    id: index + 1,
    name: value
  };
})
```

You can check a working example [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20types%20%3D%20%5B'Old'%2C%20'New'%2C%20'Template'%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20objects%20%3D%20types.map((value%2C%20index)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20index%20%2B%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20value%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(objects)%3B).

Comment: I tried this but the resulting array contains objects whose id's are proper but the name field contains another object with id and name fields and not just the string.

Comment: that can't happen unless you have something else but strings in the types array. I added a working playground link where you can see the solution working. :)

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right. I was experimenting with the wrong array while testing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of above problem is the map() method of JavaScript or Type Script.

> map() method creates a new array with the results of calling 
>   a provided function on every element in the calling array.
>
> ```
> let newArray = arr.map((currentvalue,index,array)=>{
> return Element of array
> });
> ```

```
/*map() method creates a new array with the results of calling 
a provided function on every element in the calling array.*/

     let types = [
         'Old',
         'New',
         'Template'
        ];


  /*
    let newArray = arr.map((currentvalue,index,array)=>{
         return Element of array
     });
  */


   let Obj = types.map((value, i) => {
         let data = {
                 id: i + 1,
                 name: value
             };

      return data;
    });

    console.log("Obj", Obj);
```

Please follow following links:

[TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F*map()%20method%20creates%20a%20new%20array%20with%20the%20results%20of%20calling%20%0D%0Aa%20provided%20function%20on%20every%20element%20in%20the%20calling%20array.*%2F%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20types%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20'Old'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20'New'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20'Template'%0D%0A%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F*%0D%0Alet%20newArray%20%3D%20arr.map((currentvalue%2Cindex%2Carray)%3D%3E%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Element%20of%20array%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A*%2F%0D%0Alet%20Obj%20%3D%20types.map((value%2C%20i)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20data%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20i%20%2B%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20value%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20data%3B%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(%22Obj%22%2C%20Obj)%3B)

[JS-Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vsvaibhav2016/kqc1m25p/)

> We can achieve the solution of above problem by for loop :

```
let types = [
    "One",
    "Two",
    "Three"
];

let arr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < types.length; i++){
    let data = {
        id: i + 1,
        name: types[i]
    };
    arr.push(data);
}

console.log("data", arr);
```